# How to startup apps added in Azure VM

Tags: windows, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a simple console application runs in Azure VM. What I did is creating a Local Group Policy for this app but it works in the background process.

Is it possible to run the app on windows startup normally. Not in the background??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the Task Scheduler to create a new task?

I ran the Task Scheduler on my local machine to run a Console Application that I just created. When it got triggered, the console app ran in the foreground by default.

See 2 screenshots below. It should work the same on a VM, but let me know if you have any issues with it, and I'll troubleshoot further.

[image: Task Scheduler]

[image: Console App]